# Oozie java action-retry option

Tags: java, oozie

I am trying to repeat a java action in every 1 minute with maximum 6 retries.
   I tried below code.

```
**Workflow.xml**

<workflow-app name="FilePoller" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="FilePoller"/>
    <action name="FilePoller" retry-max="10" retry-interval="1">
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <main-class>com.test.Utils</main-class>
            <arg>${input1}</arg>
            <arg>${inputDir}</arg>
            <archive>lib/filepollingscheduler.jar#filepollingscheduler.jar</archive>
        </java>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>

**Java code snippet:**

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(inputFilePattern);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(path.getName());
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Matches found");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No matches found");
                System.exit(1);
            }
```

If no matches are found, I want to retry the action.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify why your current configuration isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally System.exit() will cause an action failure even if it's 0.

http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action

You should let main() finish when a match found or throw an exception.

```
public static void main(...) {
    ...
    if(!matcher.find())
        throw new MatchNotFoundException();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe capture-output and a decision node will be a useful option for you. You may give a try of it. I worked something similar to this but not exactly as your requirements.

Once the workflow executes we should capture the output as {true or false} regarding if matches found or not. based on the result the decision can be taken whether to execute the workflow again or should stop.